# rosandroid tutorial_pubsub connection bewteen RosTextView and Talker-message

Tags: ros, rosandroid, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the talker the message is published

in the res/layout a rostextview is created

where is the link that makes the rostextview show the message?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189162/rosandroid-tutorial_pubsub-connection-bewteen-rostextview-and-talker-message/) by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you indicate what wasn't clear in the extended answer to your [previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/188778/pubsub-tutorial-change-string/?answer=188784#post-id-188784)?

If you want the actual source, see RosTextView.java in `org.ros.android.view`, lines [68 to 92](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/blob/hydro/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/main/java/org/ros/android/view/RosTextView.java#L68-L92) (this is the Hydro version):

```
public void onStart(ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
  Subscriber<T> subscriber = connectedNode.newSubscriber(topicName, messageType);
  subscriber.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<T>() {
    @Override
    public void onNewMessage(final T message) {
      if (callable != null) {
        post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            setText(callable.call(message));
          }
        });
      } else {
        post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            setText(message.toString());
          }
        });
      }
      postInvalidate();
    }
  });
}
```

The `onNewMessage(..)` method essentially calls the callback registered earlier by the user, which in the case of a `std_msgs::String` could just return the string itself.

---

Btw: you might be interested in the [ROS Java Special Interest Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-java).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-08-07**:
ok... :) ... i guess i lost sight of the wood for the trees yesterday - should have looked in my onCreate in the MainActivity - i added a whole lot of stuff in between meanwhile

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-07**:
So, question answered then?